# Check and count same word on each array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been successfully check same word on 2 different array, but my main problem if there is array contain same word of "picture" like on **array number 3 -> 3**, it just give me result 1.
I want it display exact result like 2 because **array number 3 -> 3** contain two "picture" word

**Array 1**

```
Array
(
    [0] => royalty
    [1] => free
    [2] => picture
)
```

**Array 2**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Affordable and search from millions of royalty free picture
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => from millions of royalty picture
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Provides free picture upload and hosting
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Post your picture here Get permanent links picture
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Choose your own unique username to access image
        )

)
```

**Result**

```
Array 1
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
Array 2
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
Array 3
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 0
)
```

**Here is my code**

```
$array1 = array('royalty', 'free', 'picture');

for ($i=0; $i < count($array1); $i++) { 
$array2 = array(
    array('Affordable and search from millions of royalty free'),
    array('from millions of royalty picture'),
    array('Provides free picture upload and hosting'),
    array('Post your picture here Get permanent links picture'),
    array('Choose your own unique username to access image')
);

foreach($array2 as &$item) {
    $item = count(array_intersect(explode(' ', $array1[$i]), explode(' ', $item[0])));
}

print_r($array2); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the array order cause intersect return all array from the first array. Check the below code i have modified. It may helps. Thanks

```
   $array1 = array('royalty', 'free', 'picture');

   for ($i=0; $i < count($array1); $i++) { 
   $array2 = array(
   array('Affordable and search from millions of royalty free'),
   array('from millions of royalty picture'),
   array('Provides free picture upload and hosting'),
   array('Post your picture here Get permanent links picture picture'),
   array('Choose your own unique username to access image')
  );

  foreach($array2 as &$item) {
      $item = count(array_intersect(explode(' ', $item[0]), explode(' ',     $array1[$i])));
  }

print_r($array2);
```

I have modified here

```
**$item = count(array_intersect(explode(' ', $item[0]), explode(' ',     $array1[$i])));**
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

$array1 = array('royalty', 'free', 'picture');

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($array1); $i++) { 
    $array2 = array(
        array('Affordable and search from millions of royalty free'),
        array('from millions of royalty picture'),
        array('Provides free picture upload and hosting'),
        array('Post your picture here Get permanent links picture'),
        array('Choose your own unique username to access image')
    );

    foreach($array2 as &$item) {        
        $counts = array_count_values(explode(' ', $item[0]));
        $item = isset($counts[$array1[$i]]) ? $counts[$array1[$i]] : 0;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array2); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `array_intersect`, but with the parameters in the wrong order. Personally I think `array_filter` is probably a better fit here, mainly because it gives better readable code imo.

I went ahead and rewrote your code to work with the array_filter method. Let's have a look at it first:

```
$searchTerms = ['royalty', 'free', 'picture'];
$sentences = [
    'Affordable and search from millions of royalty free',
    'from millions of royalty picture',
    'Provides free picture upload and hosting',
    'Post your picture here Get permanent links picture',
    'Choose your own unique username to access image'
];
$result = [];
foreach ($searchTerms as $q) { 
    foreach($sentences as $sentence) {
        $result[$q][] = count(array_filter(explode(' ', $sentence), function($word) use ($q) {
            return $word == $q;
        } ));
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

The output will look like this:

```
Array
(
    [royalty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

    [free] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

    [picture] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 0
        )

)
```

I hope you'll forgive me for the somewhat unrelated refactoring I did along the way:

- declare all the variables outside the loop. No need to redeclare them on each iteration, since they won't change.
- gave some more sensible names to the variables
- changed the format of the "sentences" slightly, not sure why they where inside another array.
- made the output an associative array, just because it made it easier to verify the result.

The main difference is the use of the `array_filter` method in stead of the `array_intersect`. I think the function speaks for itself, but feel free to ask if anything is unclear.